# Cant create migration phinx

Tags: php, mysql, phinx

When I try create migration I get this exception, but I have not got curly braces in my migration path

[Exception]
You probably used curly braces to define the migration path in your Phinx configuration file, but no directories have been matched using this pattern. You need to create a migration directory manually.

My config:

```
paths:
  migrations: %%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/migrations
  seeds: %%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/seeds

environments:
  default_migration_table: phinxlog
  default_database: development
  production:
    adapter: mysql
    host: localhost
    name: production_db
    user: root
    pass: ''
    port: 3306
    charset: utf8

  development:
    adapter: mysql
    host: localhost
    name: development_db
    user: root
    pass: ''
    port: 3306
    charset: utf8

  testing:
    adapter: mysql
    host: localhost
    name: testing_db
    user: root
    pass: ''
    port: 3306
    charset: utf8

version_order: creation
```

Answer (score 11):

Just came across this same error when trying to setup CakePHP & Phinx.
Was caused by missing out the directory when running the Phinx command.
Docs say to init the system type :

```
phinx init .
```

(If Phinx was installed via composer use : `vendor/bin/phinx init .` )

If you miss out the '.' you get the error you have described. It looks like Phinx doesn't have a default setting of using the currently working directory.
http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/commands.html#the-init-command.
You can fix the issue by ether re-running the Phinx command or by manually creating the folders :

```
mkdir -p db/migrations db/seeds
```

Hope this helps anyone searching in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if you ever found your answer, but I fixed this error by manually creating the **db/migrations** directory in the root. You might have to do the same with **db/seeds**.

Comment: The documentation says you have to create `db/migrations` then run `vendor/bin/phinx init`, then `vendor/bin/phinx create ...`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are running "php vendor/bin/phinx " from inside the migration directory. Try this from root directory. I was getting same error and fixed from root folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 3.0 or 4.0 your `paths` might need updating..

```
    'paths' => [
        'migrations' => '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/config/Migrations',
        'seeds' => '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/config/Seeds'
    ],
```

Worked for me.